# Extracting lines from text files in a folder based on the numbers in another file

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have a file ff.txt that looks as follows

```
*ABNA.txt
 356
 24
 36
 112
*AC24.txt
 457
 458
 321
 2
```

ABNA.txt and AC24.txt are the files in the folder named foo1. Based on the numbers in the ff.txt file, I want to extract the lines from the corresponding files in the foo1 folder and create the new files with the existing file names in another folder foo2.
If the third or fourth column of ABNA.txt file contain 356,24,36,112 numbers, extract that lines and save it to another folder foo2 as ABNA.txt.

ABNA.txt file in the folder foo1 looks as follows

```
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
ghf qza 12  123
dfg qza 36  55
```

AC24.txt file in the folder foo1 looks as follows

```
hjb hkg 457 167
ghf qza  2  165
sar sar 234 321
dfg qza 345 345
```

Output:

ABNA.txt file in the folder foo2

```
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
dfg qza 36  55
```

AC24.txt file in the folder foo2

```
hjb hkg 457 167
ghf qza  2  165
sar sar 234 321
```

your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir -p foo2
awk '
    function process_file(filename, values,     filein, fileout, line, f) {
        if (filename == "") return
        filein = "./foo1/" filename
        fileout = "./foo2/" filename
        while ((getline line < filein) > 0) {
            split(line, f)
            if (f[3] in values || f[4] in values) {
                print line > fileout
            } 
        }
    }

    /^\*/ {
        process_file(filename, values)
        filename = substr($0, 2)
        delete values
        next
    }
    { values[$1] }
    END { process_file(filename, values) }
' ff.txt
```

Comment: Looks good. However, one small change. OP wants to look for 3rd and 4th column. Using `if (f[3] in values)` misses one line from each output file.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATED**

This is a pure `bash` solution (`grep` was removed):

```
#!/bin/bash

file=
s=()

grp() { r="${s[@]}";r="\b("${r// /|}")\b";
  while read w; do [[ $w =~ $r ]] && echo $w;done <foo1/$file >foo2/$file
}

while read a; do
  if [[ $a =~ ^\* ]]; then
     [ -n "$file" ] && grp
     file=${a#\*}
     s=()
  else s=(${s[@]} $a)
  fi
done < ff.txt
[ -n "$file" ] && grp

#See input and output files
for i in foo1/*;{ echo %% in $i; cat $i;}
for i in foo2/*;{ echo %% out $i; cat $i;}
```

Output

```
%% in foo1/ABNA.txt
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
ghf qza 12  123
dfg qza 36  55
%% in foo1/AC24.txt
hjb hkg 457 167
ghf qza  2  165
sar sar 234 321
dfg qza 345 345
%% out foo2/ABNA.txt
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
dfg qza 36  55
%% out foo2/AC24.txt
hjb hkg 457 167
ghf qza  2  165
sar sar 234 321
```

In the while-loop it parses the `ff.txt` file. If a line starts with `*` then the `file` environment variable is set. If not starts with `*` then it is a number and added to the `s` array. If a new filename found and there is an old filename set then it calls the `grp` function which does the real work.

The function `grp` creates a regex in `\b(num1|num2...)\b` format. The `\b` is to match only complete numbers. So `\b24\b` will not match to `245`. The while-loop reads the file from `foo1`, matches each line against the regex and writes the file with the same name to directory `foo2`. It does not checks if `foo2` directory exist.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed and Bash):

```
folder1=foo1
folder2=foo2
sed -r '/^\*/!{s/\s*//g;H;$!d};1{h;d};x;s/\n/ /;s/\n/|/g;s#\*(.*) (.*)#<'"$folder1"'/\1 sed -nr '\''/^(\\S+\\s+){2,3}\\b(\2)\\b/w '"$folder2"'/\1'\''#' ff.txt | sh
```

This turns the `ff.txt` file into a script which is piped into the `sh` command. The user must first set bash variables `$folder1` and `$folder2` to the directories containing the source files and the ouput files respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this -

```
awk '
BEGIN {
    readpath=sprintf("%s", "/path/to/foo1")
    writepath=sprintf("%s", "/path/to/foo2")
    }
$0~/\*/ {
    file = substr($1,2)
    while ((getline var < (readpath"/"file)) > 0) {
        split (var, a, " ")
        ary[a[3]]=var
        ary[a[4]]=var
        }
    }
($1 in ary) {
    print ary[$1] > (writepath"/"file)
    }' foo.txt
```

#### Explaination:

- Set the read path and write path in **BEGIN** statement.
- For lines that has filenames in **foo.txt** file
- Use **substr** to capture the filename in variable called **file**
- Read the file in a variable called **var**.
- **split** the variable **var** to use column 3 and 4 as index to array **ary**.
- From **foo.txt** file if first column is present in the array as index write it to the file.

#### Test:

```
[jaypal:~/temp/test] ls
foo.txt foo1    foo2

[jaypal:~/temp/test] cat foo.txt
*ABNA.txt
356
24
36
112
*AC24.txt
457
458
321
2

[jaypal:~/temp/test] ls foo1/
ABNA.txt AC24.txt

[jaypal:~/temp/test] head foo1/*
==> foo1/ABNA.txt <==
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
ghf qza 12  123
dfg qza 36  55

==> foo1/AC24.txt <==
hjb hkg 457 167
ghf qza  2  165
sar sar 234 321
dfg qza 345 345

[jaypal:~/temp/test] ls foo2/
[jaypal:~/temp/test] 

[jaypal:~/temp/test] awk '
BEGIN {
    readpath=sprintf("%s", "./foo1")
    writepath=sprintf("%s", "./foo2")
    }
$0~/\*/ {
    file = substr($1,2)
    while ((getline var < (readpath"/"file)) > 0) {
        split (var, a, " ")
        ary[a[3]]=var
        ary[a[4]]=var
        }
    }
($1 in ary) {
    print ary[$1] > (writepath"/"file)
    }' foo.txt

[jaypal:~/temp/test] ls foo2/
ABNA.txt AC24.txt

[jaypal:~/temp/test] head foo2/*
==> foo2/ABNA.txt <==
dfg qza 356 245
hjb hkg 455 24
dfg qza 36  55

==> foo2/AC24.txt <==
hjb hkg 457 167
sar sar 234 321
ghf qza  2  165
```